# Setting a domain in Heroku and GoDaddy without www prefix

Tags: dns, godaddy, cname, no-www, heroku

I just purchased a new domain in `GoDaddy` lets call it `example.com`. I want to connect this domain to my `Heroku` app, so I went to the settings in `Heroku` and under `Domains` section I added the followings options for my domain:

1. `www.example.com`
2. `example.com`

Then, in `GoDaddy`, under DNS management I created two `CNAME` records

[image]

I used the DNS targets that I got from `Heroku` for each of the records.
The wild card got the DNS target from `example.com` and the `www` got the DNS target from `www.example.com`.

Now, I wanted to test this setup so I tried to use `GET` request in Postman. I tried `http://www.example.com` and got 200 and the response I was expecting. However,
when I tried `http://example.com` (without the `www` prefix) I didn't get any response but an error instead:

```
Error: write EPROTO 140275225778376:error:10000458:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 112
```

Is this setup that I mention is correct? If I want to support both of the domain with and without the `www` prefix what is the correct way to set this up?

Comment: See also [Is there a way to forward my Google domain root to www?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137960/is-there-a-way-to-forward-my-google-domain-root-to-www) where somebody wants to make the bare domain work with Heroku from Google domains.  The answer is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a DNS record for the bare domain (also called the "domain apex".) You can add a record for the domain apex either by leaving the subdomain field blank or by entering `@` for the subdomain. I'm not sure which would work at Goaddy.

The problem is that you can't use a `CNAME` record for the domain apex.  You can only use `A` records there. Heroku requires that you point to their servers by name rather than by IP address because they may change the IP address of your hosting at any time without notice.  See [The Limitations of DNS A-Records | Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains).

To point the naked domain to Heroku for hosting you need to use a DNS provider than supports entering a name in the apex, but serves it as an `A` record by IP address. This type of synthetic record is usually called an `ALIAS` or `ANAME` DNS record.

Unfortunately Godaddy does not offer `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records in their DNS hosting. You will need to either let Godaddy redirect the bare domain to `www` or find a new DNS host.

I would not recommend allowing Godaddy to redirect your bare domain to `www`. There are several problems:

- Godaddy redirection has been subtly broken for years in a way that hurts SEO.  See [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)
- Godaddy doesn't offer HTTPS forwarding for domains, so `https://example.com/` is never going to work.
- I'm not sure that you can configure GoDaddy to forward just the domain apex without also forwarding the subdomains.

You should instead choose a different DNS host that offers `ANAME`/`ALIAS` functionality and move your DNS hosting by changing the `NS` records at Godaddy to point to your new DNS host. See [Godaddy's instructions for editing NS records](https://godaddy.com/help/edit-an-ns-record-19213)

Comment: "You can only use A records there." Or `AAAA` ;-) As for CNAME at apex feature in a sane/standard way more and more DNS providers should support HTTPS DNS records (not to be confused with HTTPS the protocol) as browsers are on board to support it. That does not solve the problem right now for all clients though obviously.